# Archive keystroke in Geary or Thunderbird

Tags: pantheon-mail, thunderbird

I have multiple email addresses. When I use Geary or Thunderbird to access gmail then I can press "A" to archive the current message. However, there is no such option when I access emails from other email addresses (such as university emails).

Is there a way to add an archive keystroke in Geary or in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Geary, this isn't currently possible, but the development team is [planning to add that feature](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1546259).

In Thunderbird, you can set up archiving for non-Gmail accounts by [following these instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/archived-messages#w_how-do-i-configure-archiving).